# ag-grid v22 throws warning unmet peer dependency

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/

If you decide to use @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules then you do not need to specify @ag-grid-community/all-modules too. @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules will contain all Community modules.

But I get the warning if there is no @ag-grid-community/all-modules

warning " > @ag-grid-community/react@22.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@ag-grid-community/core@~22.1.0".

any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post your ag-grid related packages?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. You should open a support ticket.

In the meantime, if everything works ok, ignore the warning..
If it doesn't work, import the missing module.